# On IE11, cannot type in input box after removing iframe with contenteditable=true on body while that iframe was in focus

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-11, contenteditable, froala

I have an iframe which has its body set to `contenteditable=true`. When I remove that iframe from the DOM, all of my other textareas and inputs become unresponsive to user input. The objects still report that they have focus and still will claim to be receiving onkeydown events, but the contents of those elements never changes as a result of those events.

**After I remove an iframe with <body contenteditable=true> from the DOM, how can I make sure that other input fields remain functional?**

This is the structure of the Froala Editor when `iframe: true`.

Requirements:

- This only happens on IE 11. If you cannot reproduce it, please post your version of IE 11 and OS (I'm using 11.309.16299.0 on Windows 10).
- The structure of the iframe cannot change, I know that not having the contenteditable inside an iframe will solve this problem, this is a technical requirement for other code that goes beyond the scope of this question.
- The jQuery library, and any other third party library, is not available in this environment.
- This is not the only iframe in scope in my actual environment, so changes to all iframes will not work.

*Ideally, I would have some vanilla javascript function that gets called after the iframe is removed from the DOM that sets the state of the browser such that input fields return to their normal state.*

Code can be found below as well as a handy link to a codepen.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script>
    function removeIframe() {
        var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
        var iframe =  document.getElementById("iframe");
        parent.removeChild(iframe);
    }

    function setContent() {
        document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.write("<html><body contenteditable='true'>Step 1: type something here</body></html>");
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="parent" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
  <div> This is a test for <b>IE 11 only</b>.
  </div>
    <input id="input" placeholder="Step 3: Try to type something into this input, note that you cannot, that's the problem.">
    <iframe id="iframe" onload="setContent()">
    </iframe>

    <button type="button" onclick="removeIframe()">Step 2: click this button to remove the iframe that you just typed into</button>
</div>

</body>
```

The below link to codepen presents a simple reproduction of the problem.

https://codepen.io/glenpierce/pen/vRgyXe?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

From: [Window events lost after removing iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574062/window-events-lost-after-removing-iframe) which was expressly not an IE issue, I found that `window.focus()` solves the problem.

```
function removeIframe() {
        var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
        var iframe =  document.getElementById("iframe");
        parent.removeChild(iframe);
        window.focus(); //new code here
    }
```